# How to load index.html file from local directory in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, zip, wkwebview

I have been downloading zip file from server and extracting the zip file in local directory.

**ie, /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A7B8DF1-AAA4-442E-99C9-82616FC3E192/Documents/assets.zip**

**Unzip path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A7B8DF1-AAA4-442E-99C9-82616FC3E192/Library/Caches/47B7913E-A0B2-429D-AD91-AA3367EFB2AE**

From unzipped folder, i need to load index.html to WkWebView. But i could able to find folder but not able load into webview.

here is code for download zip file and extracting zip file in local directory:

```
 let url = URL(string: v)
 FileDownloader.loadFileAsync(url: url!) { (path, error) in
    print("PDF File downloaded to : \(path!)")

    guard let unzipPath = self.tempUnzipPath() else {
       return
    }
    print("Unzip path:", unzipPath)

    let success: Bool = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: path!,
                                               toDestination: unzipPath,
                                               preserveAttributes: true,
                                               overwrite: true,
                                               nestedZipLevel: 1,
                                               password: nil,
                                               error: nil,
                                               delegate: nil,
                                               progressHandler: nil,
                                               completionHandler: nil)
    if success != false {
       print("Success unzip")
    } else {
       print("No success unzip")
       return
    }

    var items: [String]
    do {
       items = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: unzipPath)
       print("array item for unzip", items[0])               
    } catch {
       return
    }

    for v in items[0] {
       print("vv index.html", v)
       self.buildAry.append(v)
    }

    print("build ary", self.buildAry)
    let ss = self.buildAry[0]
    print("index html", ss)
 }
```

here is my console output:

```
 Success unzip
 array item for unzip build
vv index.html b
vv index.html u
vv index.html i
vv index.html l
vv index.html d
 build ary 2020-02-07 19:40:44.480754+0530[9847:2135988] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
["b", "u", "i", "l", "d"]
 index html b
```

How to load index.html into WKWebView from unzipped folder. Any help much appreciated pls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to open a local file in WKWebView you can call `loadFileURL(URL, allowReadAccessTo: URL)` on your WKWebView instance.

Edit after your comment:
If you know, that your index.html will always be in „build“ folder you can do:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: unzipPath, isDirectory: false).appendingPathComponent("build").appendindPathComponent("Index.html", isDirectory: false)   
myWKWebView.loadFileURL(url, allowsReadAccessTo: url)
```

If you need more help, please comment.

Comment: after unzip found folder name called 'build' inside build folder there is index.html file. How can i load index.html file from build folder.

Comment: it shows main thread log like this Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[WKUserContentController addScriptMessageHandler:name:]
PID: 10494, TID: 2491477, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x137eeaa10 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            print("md5 storage form url", self.md5FormURL)
                        
                            self.webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: self.md5FormURL)
                            

                        }

Comment: Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` is right. Do you need more help or are your problems solved?

Comment: yes, its taking time to load html file from unzipped folder more than 5 sec

Comment: @ParameswaranV Did you try it with `wkwebview.loadFileURL` as I showed?

Comment: I asked because you wrote `loadHTMLString()` in an earlier comment

Comment: Please update your question with current code, or even better post a new question with your current code and problem.

Comment: can you check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168084/how-to-load-local-directory-inside-iframe-in-ios-swift